# How to merge two functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function

I have two functions in my MATLAB code and I want that output of one function is used as an input of another function.  How can I implement this?

```
medianfilter1.m
```

The code is:

```
function ans = medianfilter(angstanding)
[m,n] = size(angstanding);
ans = zeros(m,n);
x = angstanding(:,1);
y = angstanding(:,2);
z = angstanding(:,3);
svm = angstanding(:,4);

ans(:,1) = medfilt1(x);
ans(:,2) = medfilt1(y);
ans(:,3) = medfilt1(z);
ans(:,4) = medfilt1(svm);
```

Second Function is: `windowing.m`

Code:

```
function [wx,wy,wz,wsvm] = windowing(currentdata)


% i = 1;
% obseen = 128;

 [r,c] = size(currentdata);

%  display(r);
% while obseen <= r
%     i = i +1;
%     obseen = obseen + 64;
%     
%   
% end;
% display(i);
residue  = rem((r - 128),64);
rows = floor((r-128)/64);

rows = rows + 1;


 wx = zeros(rows,128);

 wy = zeros(rows,128);
 wz = zeros(rows,128);
 wsvm = zeros(rows,128);

vectorx = currentdata(:,1);
vectory = currentdata(:,2);
vectorz = currentdata(:,3);
vectorsvm = currentdata(:,4);

for i = 1:rows
    x = (64 * (i-1)) + 1;
    if i ~= rows
        lastj = 128;
    else 
        break ;
    end;

        for j = 1:lastj

                wx(i,j) = vectorx(x);
                wy(i,j) = vectory(x);
                wz(i,j) = vectorz(x);
                wsvm(i,j) = vectorsvm(x);
                x = x + 1;

        end;


end;
```

and I want that result of `medianfilter.m` is to be fed into `windowing.m`.

Below is what i tried: `merge.m`

```
function ans = medianfilter(rawdataset_train_acc)
[m,n] = size(rawdataset_train_acc);
ans = zeros(m,n);
x = rawdataset_train_acc(:,1);
y = rawdataset_train_acc(:,2);
z = rawdataset_train_acc(:,3);
svm =rawdataset_train_acc(:,4);

ans(:,1) = medfilt1(x);
ans(:,2) = medfilt1(y);
ans(:,3) = medfilt1(z);
ans(:,4) = medfilt1(svm);

function [wx,wy,wz,wsvm] = windowing(ans)


% i = 1;
% obseen = 128;

 [r,c] = size(ans);

%  display(r);
% while obseen <= r
%     i = i +1;
%     obseen = obseen + 64;
%     
%   
% end;
% display(i);
residue  = rem((r - 128),64);
rows = floor((r-128)/64);

rows = rows + 1;


 wx = zeros(rows,128);

 wy = zeros(rows,128);
 wz = zeros(rows,128);
 wsvm = zeros(rows,128);

vectorx = ans(:,1);
vectory = ans(:,2);
vectorz = ans(:,3);
vectorsvm = ans(:,4);

for i = 1:rows
    x = (64 * (i-1)) + 1;
    if i ~= rows
        lastj = 128;
    else 
        break ;
    end;

        for j = 1:lastj

                wx(i,j) = vectorx(x);
                wy(i,j) = vectory(x);
                wz(i,j) = vectorz(x);
                wsvm(i,j) = vectorsvm(x);
                x = x + 1;

        end;


end;
```

I tried above but didn't achieve what i wanted. How can i do this?

Comment: You want `f(g(x))`? Please give some more details.

Comment: @ZizyArcher please check the question above, i've given detail explanation with code.

Comment: Anish, @ZizyArcher's answer is still the correct one. Trying to put the two functions into one .m file is just going to make your life harder.

Comment: I proposed both. It seems that we have a starter here so better show him both options. And if you dont know how to merge them I think that it does not help to understand the structure of a function file if someone says just execute them behind each other

Comment: To my understanding, it appears to be a very basic question about assigning outputs of functions to variables etc. Reading the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-and-data-types.html) should help. BTW, using `ans` as a variable name is a very bad idea, since it can be overwritten by something completely irrelevant if you're not careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what are you attempting. It seems to me that what you want is indeed the composite function.

Once you have a function prototype/definition, you have to call it.

For example, if you have functions to compute the cube and the square of a number (cubeExample and squareExample respectively) and you want to compute the the 6th power of a number `x`:

```
result = squareExample(cubeExample(x))

function r = squareExample(a)
    r = a*a;
end

function r = cubeExample(a)
    r = a*a*a;
end
```

Also note that the names of the function definitions are *mute*, that means that don't really matter how you name them.

In this case would be something like

```
[wx,wy,wz,wsvm] = windowing(medianfilter(angstanding))
```

following your ideas, assuming the input format of windowing is the same as the output of medianfilter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one function `[output_a]=a(input)` and a function `[output_b] =b(input)`
you can simply stack them as @zizy archer did already recomend.It would look like this:

```
sample_input=3;    
sample_ouput_var=a(b(sample_input));
```

what this block does is taking the sampel input feeding into b() taking the output of b and directly feeding it into a. so in pseudo code:

```
sample_input=3;
sample_outputb=b(sample_input):
sample_outputa=a(sample_output_b):
```

In your special case I would do it like this

```
outa,outb, outc, outd =windowing(medianfilter(input))
```

If you want to merge two functins I would take the output of the second function and the input of the first one so in pseudocode this would be

```
function output1=examplefunc(input1):
      output1=input1*input1
end
```

and a second function

```
function output2=examplefunc2(input2):
     output2=input2+input2;
end
```

merge them by:

```
function outputmerged=merged_func(input1):
   output1=input1*input1;
   input2=output1;
   output_merged=input2+input2;
end
```

In your code example it looks like this:

```
function [wx,wy,wz,wsvm] = medianfilter_windowing_merge(rawdataset_train_acc)
%input from medianfilter output from windowing
[m,n] = size(angstanding);
ans = zeros(m,n);
x = angstanding(:,1);
y = angstanding(:,2);
z = angstanding(:,3);
svm = angstanding(:,4);

ans(:,1) = medfilt1(x);
ans(:,2) = medfilt1(y);
ans(:,3) = medfilt1(z);
ans(:,4) = medfilt1(svm);

%here happens the handover from one function to the other everything above is from the medianfilter.m everything below is from windowing 
currentdata=ans

[r,c] = size(currentdata);


residue  = rem((r - 128),64);
rows = floor((r-128)/64);

rows = rows + 1;


 wx = zeros(rows,128);

 wy = zeros(rows,128);
 wz = zeros(rows,128);
 wsvm = zeros(rows,128);

vectorx = currentdata(:,1);
vectory = currentdata(:,2);
vectorz = currentdata(:,3);
vectorsvm = currentdata(:,4);

for i = 1:rows
    x = (64 * (i-1)) + 1;
    if i ~= rows
        lastj = 128;
    else 
        break ;
    end;

        for j = 1:lastj

                wx(i,j) = vectorx(x);
                wy(i,j) = vectory(x);
                wz(i,j) = vectorz(x);
                wsvm(i,j) = vectorsvm(x);
                x = x + 1;

        end;


end;
```

Comment: please check the code above. i have give complete details